# find exact match and case insensitive files on non-Windows using ansible

Tags: find, ls, filenames, case-sensitivity

i'm able to find files case insensitive using the below ansible play and unix command.

```
- name: Check if file exists with exact name
  shell: "ls {{ userfile }}"
  register: filefound
  ignore_error: yes
  when: userfile is defined      

- name: Get case insensitive file listing
  shell: "ls {{ userfile | dirname }} | grep -i {{ userfile | basename }}"
  register: ignorecasefilefound
  ignore_error: yes
  when: userfile is defined and filefound.rc != 0
```

Let's consider the user provided `/tmp/DB_promotion.sql`

whereas there are the below two files under tmp:

```
/tmp/db_promotion.sql_bkp
/tmp/db_promotion.sql
```

With my logic the command `ls {{ userfile | dirname }} | grep -i {{ userfile | basename }}` returns:

```
/tmp/db_promotion.sql_bkp
/tmp/db_promotion.sql
```

whereas i was just expecting exact case-insensitive match i.e:

```
/tmp/db_promotion.sql
```

I'm using both Solaris & Linux.

Kindly suggest how.

Comment: Don't run shell commands. Use a module. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_files_modules.html